# Ajax post request in laravel 5 return error 500. No logs

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, error-handling

Im getting internal server error 500. unfortunately there is no logs to see what causes it.

here is my ajax calling it :

```
 createRide(event) {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Hello', $("#form-create-ride").serialize());
    $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/dispatcher',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken },
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("#form-create-ride").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Accept', data);
            this.props.completed(data);
        }.bind(this)
    });
}
```

this is from : dispatcher-admin.js:455 (see error in console below).

here is the error :

> 

```
jquery-1.12.3.min.js:4 POST http://example.com/admin/dispatcher 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-1.12.3.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-1.12.3.min.js:4
createRide @ dispatcher-admin.js:455
ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.js:9073
executeDispatch @ react-dom.js:3031
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.js:3054
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.js:2456
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.js:2467
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.js:15509
processEventQueue @ react-dom.js:2670
runEventQueueInBatch @ react-dom.js:9097
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.js:9108
handleTopLevelImpl @ react-dom.js:9185
perform @ react-dom.js:14810
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.js:8862
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.js:12938
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.js:9260
15:02:10.204
```

Comment: Can you Right-click the network request and share the cURL from there?

Comment: Ohh i think you have saved me i found this in network request's preview section:

"Unknown column 'os_id' in 'field list

will add and check response

Comment: That's great. Keep Hacking!

Comment: I could be wrong but an error like that should also show in the Laravel log as well: `storage/logs/laravel.log`.

Comment: nope, unfortunately it was not showing there, i found it in network requests using inspect elements, as @AnujRaghuvanshi suggested i found error there.